# Stanford OpenIE example code compile error

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, stanford-nlp

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml generates compile time error :

> SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.EnhancedDependenciesAnnotation cannot be resolved to a type

I am running `java-8` under `eclipse 2016`. `corenlp-full-2015-12-01.zip`, `openie.jar`, `openie-models.jar` are in included in my eclipse project.

Error generated by line of:

`System.out.println(sentence.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.EnhancedDependenciesAnnotation.class).toString(SemanticGraph.OutputFormat.LIST));`

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I were to guess, this sounds like a classpath issue. What happens if you remove either openie.jar or the corenlp distribution? In theory, openie.jar should contain everything you need to run the Open IE system.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error.
What does this `package edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli;` in the first line of the code snippet mean?

I do not have much Java knowledge, I just created a Java project somewhere and included the same files as WH Sweet did.
I just found that within the corenlp project subfolder naturalli there is a OpenIEDemo.java already. Maybe the explanation for this would solve the initial problem..